# Issues with ListPlot, Placed, SwatchLegend, PlotTheme, and BaseStyle

Tags: plotting, legending

I have a particular plot I want make with the following features:

- ListPlot with three separate lists.
- Uses the monochrome plot theme.
- Has a legend.
- Has larger than default axis labels and values.

Here is the snippet of code I've tried

```
ListPlot[Table[Table[i*j, {i, 1, 100}], {j, 1, 3}], Frame -> True, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", 
  FrameLabel -> 
    {Style["Abscissa", FontSize -> 18], Style["Ordinate", FontSize -> 18]}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[
      SwatchLegend[{"Set 1", "Set 2", "Set 3"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 16], 
      {0.25, 0.75}], 
  ImageSize -> Full]
```

My issues are:

When the code is evaluated as-is, it's clearly not in monochrome. However, the plot markers are changed from plain circles.

If you remove the `BaseStyle` option, the plot does become monochrome however the legend becomes useless.

So how do I build this plot completely in monochrome, with larger fonts, and a useful legend (ie, displays the plot shapes, not colors)

Answer (score 5):

Replace `BaseStyle` with `LabelStyle` and `SwatchLegend` with `LineLegend`:

```
lp = ListPlot[Table[Table[i*j, {i, 1, 100}], {j, 1, 3}], Frame -> True, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 16}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Abscissa", FontSize -> 18], Style["Ordinate", FontSize -> 18]}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"Set 1", "Set 2", "Set 3"}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 16], {0.25, 0.75}], 
 ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

To re-size the markers in the legend, you can use

```
 MapAt[# /. Offset[x_] :> Offset[2 x] &, lp, {2}]
```

[image]

In order to use `SwatchLegend` we need to set the option value for `LegendMarkers` to the default markers used by `ListPlot`. The latter can be obtained using

```
pmarkers = PlotMarkers /. 
   Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["PlotMarkers", ListPlot];
```

Change the option `PlotLegends -> LineLegend[...]` above to

```
PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[SwatchLegend[{"Set 1", "Set 2", "Set 3"}, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 16, LegendMarkers -> pmarkers], {0.25, 0.75}]
```

to get the first picture above and use the same post-processing to get the second picture.

Comment: Thank you so much!